# Netbeans 7.1 built in terminal commands

Tags: linux, macos, netbeans, command-line, terminal

Is the built in terminal inside netbeans the exact same as the one as the one on linux/osx? The same commands, etc?

Comment: +1 Though I could trace the "internal terminal" back to NB 6.9 around mid 2007 (it seems to come from an even older community plugin), it really went for me unnoticed until today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do the same things in Netbeans Terminal as in a regular Terminal (I'm speaking for at least Netbeans v.7.1). You can even start application from there without any problem.

I don't know about osx, I'm using ubuntu but I guess it's the same behaviour too.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to use the same colors as cygwin? Because my terminal is just all white text :(

Comment: @user983323 You can custom your Terminal in `Tools->Options`, in pane `Miscellaneous` go in pane `Terminal`. Then here you can custom your terminal with your color. Hope it will help, AFAIK there is not any other way to change color...